# S3 API create bucket error on softlayer

Tags: amazon-s3, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, bucket

I'm using following code to check the existence of a bucket:

```
def check_bucket_existed(bucket_name, public_auth_endpoint):

    endpoint = 'https://' + public_auth_endpoint
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url=endpoint)

    try:
        s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
        exists = True
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        error_code = int(e.response['Error']['Code'])
        if error_code == 404:
            exists = False
        else:
            exists = True
    return exists
```

If the bucket doesn't exist, then start to create the bucket with following code:

```
def create_bucket(bucket_name, public_auth_endpoint):
    endpoint = 'https://' + public_auth_endpoint
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url=endpoint)

    if check_bucket_existed(bucket_name, public_auth_endpoint):
        print("Bucket {} existed , skip bucket creation process".format(bucket_name))
        return True
    else:
        print("Bucket {} doesn't exist, start bucket creation process.".format(bucket_name))
        try:
            s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
            if check_bucket_existed(bucket_name, public_auth_endpoint):
                print("Bucket {} created successsfully.".format(bucket_name))
                return True
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            print("Error: Unable to create the bucket : %s" % e)
            return False
```

I'm confused by the following log got when running create_bucket code:

```
Bucket td.cos.s1 doesn't exist, start bucket creation process.
Error: Unable to create the bucket : An error occurred (BucketAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.
```

In the log, first it shows bucket name to be used doesn't exist, but when start to create bucket with this name, ERROR info is prompted which shows this bucket name can't be used.

I'm using this bucket name many times, and this bucket name can be used.

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: This bucket name is used before. But it's deleted before running this create_bucket code.

Answer (score 0):

The exception:

> "The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is
>   shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and
>   try again."

The buckets are unique, so it means that another customer (it can be from other accounts) has been already created a bucket with the same name that you are trying. So I recommend to create the bucket with a different name

---

**Updated**

Your script works fine, **I had success to create bucket: td.cos.s1**(I already deleted it, for your tests). can you make double check please?

Here the result that I got:

```
False
Bucket td.cos.s1 doesn't exist, start bucket creation process.
Bucket td.cos.s1 created successsfully.
True
```

Comment: But with the method check_bucket_existed it shows that the bucket with this name doesn't exist. How to explain this?

Comment: My apologies, I already verify your script, please review the **Updated** section in my answer

Comment: This issue happened when running following code in loop for 10 times:1. create cloud object storage. 2.create bucket. 3. delete bucket. 4.delete cloud object storage.  Then there will be several times that issue happened.

Comment: Doing some tests (using a loop to create and delete bucket) I verified that sometimes it fails, I believe that the creation takes some time, in order that the bucket will be ready to be deleted or vice versa. I recommend to submit a ticket if you want to dig more on this issue, would be really helpful if you attach the full code that you tried for reproduce the issue